# Why Matplotlib.hist taking different list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the following

```
list_a_seq_of_p = [0,  1,  1,  1.5, 2.5, 3,  3,  3.5, 4.5, 5 ]
plt.plot(list_a_seq_of_p)
pyplot.hist(
    list_a_seq_of_p,
    range(11),
    histtype="step",
    cumulative=True,
    color=("r"),
    label=("A"),
)
```

And getting
[image]

This one actually draws a different array([ 1.,  4.,  5.,  8.,  9., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.], which is created run time automatically.

Comment: It is very unclear what your expected result is.  Maybe you want `plt.step(range(10), list_a_seq_of_p)`?  Note that `plt.plot(x, y)` plots `y` versus `x`. While `plt.plot(y)` plots `y` versus `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the red histogram appears to be wrong? It's not. You've got `cumulative=True` so it adds each value to make a "running total".

If you wanted both to line up, provide the same y-axis for both and set `cumulative` to `False` (or remove it since `False` is the default).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_a_seq_of_p = [0,  1,  1,  1.5, 2.5, 3,  3,  3.5, 4.5, 5 ]
plt.plot(list_a_seq_of_p, range(len(list_a_seq_of_p)))
plt.hist(
    list_a_seq_of_p,
    len(list_a_seq_of_p),
    histtype="step",
    cumulative=False,
    color=("r"),
    label=("A"),
)
```

That gives:
[image]

Btw, the 2nd parameter to `plt.hist()` is the `bins`. So which bins are you expecting? `len(list_a_seq_of_p)` above is not a sensible value for bins.

Also, be consistent with your import names. First you use `plt.plot()` and next line is `pyplot.hist()`.